# How can I show both a value and text in a dropdown?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a python application that uses flask to send information to a html page. I parsed two columns of a table to a variable and I want to use these two columns differently in the same dropdown menu. The first column should be assigned to the value of the  statement and the second column should be the text that is shown in the dropdown menu. I currently only know how to present one column.

This is the code I currently use for this:

```
<select name="WantedRole" value="WantedRole"/>
{% for row in AllRoles%}
    {% for d in row %}
        <option value="{{d}}">{{d}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

So I currently do not know how to get a different value for the `{{ d }}` assigned to value compared to the `{{ d }}` that is just the text representation.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your ORM model D type has properties id and name:

`<option value="{{d.id}}">{{d.name}}</option>`

Substitute whatever the appropriate property names are.

Note that in your original code, {{d}} is not the text representation, d represents the object returned from your DB query. Your templating engine is calling a method on the object behind the scenes to get the string representation.

Comment: This seems like an interesting way of doing this, however, how would I set the properties accordingly in my python script? I'm currently just using an `UserRoles = cur.fetchall()` and passing the UserRoles variable via the `return render_template(UserRoles=UserRoles, ...)`

Comment: You would not have to set the properties. However you define your ORM model defines the properties that you have access to. Please update your original question with the code you have that defines the UserRole model